# 6 Terminals Coming Off Switch?

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan, fans

I have a switch in a ceiling fan's wiring. It controls the direction of the fan.

So it's a two position switch, but it has 6 terminals coming off of it!

Is this switching the phase and the neutral simultaneously?

I can envision some potential problems if the switch didn't switch the wires simultaneously. Am I misunderstanding what this switch does?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't you think photos would help?

Comment: I would guess they do switch neutral and phase. What do you see the harm as switching them not simultaneously? Keep in mind the switch is probably only used once or twice a year.

Comment: @transistor Added some photos :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switch is a DPDT switch and is reversing the phase relationship between two winding's. Typically the outer terminals will be cross connected.  As far as mains voltage etc, that is circuit and motor dependent.

Comment: I've added a couple pictures it looks like pink/yellow will carry either white/gray or gray/white respectively based on the switch position.